# Hibernate 3, addScalar(), UserType [Types.BIGINT, Types.VARCHAR] 2 colums

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have a CreditCard domain:

```
class CreditCard {

Long Id 
Price value 
...

static mapping = {
        value type: PriceType,{
            column name: "VALUE_AMOUNT"
            column name: "VALUE_CURRENCY"
        } 
}
```

I want to create a report, so I create my custom Type:

```
Type priceTypeLocator = new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver()).custom(PriceType)
```

and the query:

```
def result = getSession().createSQLQuery("select ID, VALUE_AMOUNT, VALUE_CURRENCY from CreditCard")
.addScalar("ID", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
.addScalar("VALUE_AMOUNT",priceTypeLocator) //this wont work
.addScalar("VALUE_CURRENCY",priceTypeLocator) //this wont work
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CreditCard.class))
.list();
```

How to bind these 2 values (VALUE_AMOUNT and VALUE_CURRENCY) with value field in CreditCard domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved using standar types and setters:

```
 .addScalar('requestedAmountAmo', StandardBasicTypes.BIG_DECIMAL)
 .addScalar('requestedAmountCur', StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
```

And then I set the Price:

```
 void setRequestedAmountAmo(BigDecimal requestedAmountAmo) {
    requestedAmount = new Price(amount:requestedAmountAmo, currency: '')
}

void setRequestedAmountCur(String requestedAmountCur) {
    requestedAmount.currency = requestedAmountCur
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:

```
public static Type getPropertyType(Session session, Class entityClass, String propertyName) {
    return session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(entityClass).getPropertyType(propertyName);
}
```

And use it this way:

```
.addScalar("VALUE_AMOUNT", getPropertyType(session, CreditCard.class, "value_amount_poperty_name"))
```